# Калькулятор + опросник

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите как сделать опросник, который в соответствии с выбранными ответами, в конце опроса выдает определенный ценник. То есть получается два в одном: калькулятор+опрос. Не могу найти в гугле ничего подходящего, может у кого-то есть примеры такой работы и описание её реализации. Ссылки на ресурс вполне будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто присваиваете каждому вопросу какое-то значение в value, а потом проходите циклом по выбранным ответам и суммируете значения (не забывая перед этим привести их к number c помощью +):

```js
$('#count').click(function(){
  let result = 0;
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
    result += +$(this).val()
  })
  alert('Цена: '+result+' рублей');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>1. Вопрос 1</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="first" id="first1" value="5" /><label for="first1">Ответ 1-1</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="first" id="first2" value="10" /><label for="first2">Ответ 1-2</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="first" id="first3" value="15" /><label for="first3">Ответ 1-3</label><br />
<br />
<b>2. Вопрос 2</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="second" id="second1" value="5" /><label for="second1">Ответ 2-1</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="second" id="second2" value="10" /><label for="second2">Ответ 2-2</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="second" id="second3" value="15" /><label for="second3">Ответ 2-3</label><br />
<br />
<b>3. Вопрос 3</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="third" id="third1" value="5" /><label for="third1">Ответ 3-1</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="third" id="third2" value="10" /><label for="third2">Ответ 3-2</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="third" id="third3" value="15" /><label for="third3">Ответ 3-3</label><br />
<br />
<button id="count">Посчитать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
document.getElementById('moo').addEventListener('click', function(){
  const moo1 = document.querySelector('input[name="moo1"]:checked');
  const moo2 = document.querySelector('input[name="moo2"]:checked');
  const a1 = Number(moo1.value);
  const a2 = Number(moo2.value);
  //Здесь ниже важно было поставить скобки иначе 100 + 100 станет 100100
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Вы набрали " + (a1 + a2) + " баллов. Вы общительный человек, но не очень любите общаться. У вас есть большой нераскрытый потенциал. Вы творческая личность! Когда вы родились, Марсу было пофиг."
  
});
```

```css
label {display:block; width: 200px; border: 1px solid #123; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div>Вы Бу или не Бу?</div>

  <label><input type="radio" name="moo1" value="100"><span>Бу</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="moo1" value="200"><span>Или не Бу</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="moo1" value="300"><span>Вот в чем вопрос!</span></label>

  <div>Холодно или крокодил?</div>

  <label><input type="radio" name="moo2" value="100"><span>Холодно</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="moo2" value="200"><span>Крокодил</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="moo2" value="300"><span>Крокодилу холодно</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<button id="moo">Готово!</button>
```

Но если часто делаете калькуляторы, иногда сильно помогает `data-`

Где-нибудь в элементе можно поставить `<input data-moo="15" data-boo="20"></input>` и в скрипте получать эти значения через `элемент.dataset.moo`

*Код зависит от количества вопросов и формулы... Если вопросов много, а надо посчитать всего-то сумму, можно так:

```
const check = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
let result = 0;
for ( let i = 0; i < check.length; i++){
 result = Number(result) + Number(check[i].value);
}
```

Что означает, что он кругами пройдется по первому, 2-му, i-му отмеченному элементу и на каждом круге будет суммировать новое значение к предыдущей сумме (потому result = изначально 0)